# list with deleted items does not bind correctly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view in which the user can edit all fields for a list of items and two buttons "Add" and "Delete" which should add a new item or delete all selected items, respectively.

Although the add functionality works properly, the delete option removes the correct number of items, but removes items from the end of the list regardless of which were selected.

Strangely, the correct items seem to be deleted in the controller and passed to the view, but the view renders with the last few items deleted instead of the selected ones. Here is the code:

Model:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model List<TestMvcApp.Models.TestClass>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].IsSelected)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Prop1)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Prop2)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Prop3)
            </th>
        </tr>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); ++i )
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].IsSelected)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Prop1)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Prop2)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Prop3)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="buttonPressed" value="Add" />
    <input type="submit" name="buttonPressed" value="Remove" />
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<TestClass> testList = new List<TestClass>();
        testList.Add(new TestClass());
        return View(testList);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(List<TestClass> list, string buttonPressed)
    {
        switch (buttonPressed)
        {
            case "Add":
                return Add(list);
            case "Remove":
                return Remove(list);
            default:
                return View(list);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Add(List<TestClass> list)
    {
        list.Add(new TestClass());
        return View("Index", list);
    }

    public ActionResult Remove(List<TestClass> list)
    {
        for( int i = list.Count() - 1 ; i >= 0 ; --i)
        {
            if (list[i].IsSelected)
                list.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        if (list.Count <= 0)
            list.Add(new TestClass());
        return View("Index", list);
    }
}
```

When I break at the return statement, the list contains the correct items, but the view contains only the first items (e.g. if the list has 5 items and I remove items 2 and 3, the controller will show a list with items 1,4,5 but the view will render a list with items 1,2,3).

Any ideas why this does not work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `ModelState` is causing you these headaches. Try adding `ModelState.Clear()` in your post action before you return your View.